# Python Flask Application not redirecting

Tags: python, flask, web, url

I'm trying to create a list of clickable links to external URLs. My HTML file looks like this

```
        <ul>
            {% for post in posts %}
            <li><a href={{url_for('go_to_reddit', url=post.url)}}>{{ post.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

and the python file like this

```
@app.route('/redirect/"<url>"')
def go_to_reddit(url):
    print("Redirecting to ", url)
    return redirect(url)
```

I keep getting the following error whenever I press on one of the links

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I know it's not reaching the redirect function even though it hits the URL since my console doesn't print anything.

Comment: if you trying to reach reddit site than this will return not found error. check the address of the page if there is localhost or 127.0.0.1 or your ip address it will not work. if you want to send user to reddit than you simly use `href="{{post.url}}"` if post.url is the right address of the reddit page

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think you can have quotes in a route parameter i.e. `@app.route('/redirect/"<url>"')` should be `@app.route('/redirect/<url>')` . Put another way, try dropping the quote around `<url>`
2. If you can't have quotes in a url parameter and you need to pass a complete url, then you should consider passing it as a query parameter e.g. `/redirect/?link=post.url`. Then in your handler for the route, you will do  `url = request.values.get('link', None)`

Comment: I originally had it the way you are mentioning and I still had the same problem.

Comment: If you have it the way I mentioned in my comment, then you can't just read it using ```with open``` because a static file should be accessed via a link. I have a similar use case and my credentials were uploaded to GCS so I use the format for reading from a Google Cloud Storage file. This was for a proof of concept so I didn't worry about whether uploading to google cloud storage was the best security wise